# Can you get the pattern attribute of an asp:textbox input from js to validate a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my js validate function. How can you get the pattern attribute of an asp:textbox input from js to validate the form?

```
<form id="obrasform">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox" pattern="[\d]{3}" runat="server"/>
</form>

 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#obrasform').validate({
                    ignore: [],   
                    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                        var id = jQuery(validator.errorList[0].element).closest(".tab-pane").attr('id');             
                        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                    },         
   }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('pattern')`

Answer (score 0):

Better check out asp.net [Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bwd43d0x.aspx). It much easier than creating a function for every TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup" />
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Value is invalid" ValidationGroup="myGroup" ClientValidationFunction="myCustomValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myCustomValidation(oSrc, args) {
        var filter = /[\d]{3}/;
        args.IsValid = filter.test(args.Value);
    }
</script>
```